# How to switch between the Primary Menus programmatically?

Tags: menus

Lets say i created 2 Different Primary Menus (in the Appearance > Menu .. section).
Then in the (Theme Location > Primary Navigation) Section, i can set 1 Menu to be activated.

So how can i switch between these Primary Menus at the runtime (Programmatically from the Frontend .. WITH A BUTTON CLICK or something) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it on the clientside, if you output both menus and change the visibility on the click of the button via javascript.

if you want to do this on the serverside, you could make another template or a `if` to output the menu you want to show to the user.

the only thing you have to change here is the `$args` in calling `wp_nav_menu( $args);`

Answer (score 0):

An easier thing to implement is to use `menu` parameter in place of `theme_location` when calling `wp_nav_menu` & then accepting the 2 menus id's from the user separately (in theme options maybe?)