# How to switch between two primary menus (programatically0

Tags: php, menus

I have two menus namely : "nav-menu" and "user-menu". I just want to switch (or toggle) to a specific menu between the two menus to be primary menu whenever I visit a particular page.

For ex : If I go to some particular page then my menu programatically switches to "user-menu".

I have visited [How to switch between the Primary Menus programmatically?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72525/how-to-switch-between-the-primary-menus-programmatically). However, I am still not able to figure it out.

Can someone help me by giving brief explanation of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in specific page template

```
function change_primary_menu( $menu ) {
        // you can check spesific menu id using this print and after that assign in,
        // and you can also check menu location using this print too
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($menu) ;
        echo '</pre>';

        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        //in this example im check the user role is 'user'
        if ( in_array( 'user', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
            //if yes change to user menu (19 and 21 is just example menu id)
            $menu['primary'] = 19;
        }else{
            //if not change to another menu
            $menu['primary'] = 21;
        }
    return $menu;
};

add_filter( 'theme_mod_nav_menu_locations', 'change_primary_menu', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Was printing the Array at two places. One at random page location (I know it's because of the 'print_r' ststement). But the other one was at the menu location. I guess it might have replaced the menu object with PHP Array object. On debugging more, I found out that this '$menu' variable inside the function definition was empty Array object.

Comment: if $menu is empty, that mean you dont have any menu location. But you say you have primary menu, so I think you have 'primary' as name of a menu location

Answer (score 0):

I got this worked out! I used 'wp_nav_menu_items' hook to customize the links of the menu. However, it actually dosen't specifically answers my question but it solves my problem. Here's an example for the 'PROFILE' page :-

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'set_profile_links', 10, 2 );
function set_profile_links( $items, $args ) {
    $items = '<li ><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>';
    $items .= '<li id="current-page-menu"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/my-account">PROFILE</a></li>';
    return $items;
}
```